# MariaDB performance schema digest not calculated if same query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My problem is, that if I run a query twice, the Digest and Digest_text are not calculated again in the performance_schema for the second query.
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM state;
```

Output in events_statements_history_long looks like:

SQL_TEXT: SELECT * FROM state
DIGEST: f9842414749bbcda76ef05940ebc2f84
DIGEST_TEXT: SELECT * FROM state
LOCK_TIME: 372000000

If i run the query again, events_statements_history_long looks like:

SQL_TEXT: SELECT * FROM state
DIGEST: null
DIGEST_TEXT: null
LOCK_TIME: 0

Which is also strange, that the `LOCK_TIME` value is 0 at second try. Is there maybe some optimization going on, where no DIGEST calculation is done?
I can see this behaviour in all tables which have a digest column. E.g.

- events_statements_history_long (column `digest` and `digest_text`)
- events_statements_history (column `digest` and `digest_text`)
- objects_summary_global_by_type (column `count_star` doesn't increase)
- events_statements_summary_by_digest (column `count_star` doesn't increase)

My guess is, that those values are not recalculated if the query doesn't change. Also if I have query with a `where` clause the digest is only calculated if the clause changes (e.g. from `where foo='bar'` to `where foo='foo'`) but not if doesn't change.

So my question is: Is there some setting (which I haven't found through google or the docs) to turn on digest calculation in any table on every statement?

Answer (score 0):

Was the query cache turned on?  The QC does a digest very early, then if it sees the same digest it returns the previously returned resultset.  That is, statement execution is avoided.